# calculating rolling avg for volume in a stock data

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to make scanner type where i want to calculate the avg of past 21 days vol * 3 this i want to compare with todays vol
if todays vol is greater then the 3times avg of 21 days i shouls get a Yes in colume VolBrkOut or els i should get a No
when i run my code i get only No for each date when i run the formula in ecxcel i get my right ans
(=IF(I2>(AVERAGE(I3:I24)*3),"Yes","No") excel formula

and my py code for that is

```
def add_vol_breakout_column(self, df):
  
        average_volume = df['VOLUME'].rolling(window=21).mean()
        print(average_volume)
        volume_breakout = df['VOLUME'] > (average_volume * 3)
        df['VolBrkOut'] = np.where(volume_breakout, 'Yes', 'No')
        print(f"Updated DataFrame:\n{df}")
        return df
```

when i print it get this
1451   NaN
Name: VOLUME, dtype: float64
Updated DataFrame:
SYMBOL        DATE  PCLOSE   OPEN  ...  DELIV_QTY  DELIV_PER  VWAP  VolBrkOut
1451  SATINDLTD  12-01-2023    69.8  69.95  ...     519070      28.78  74.5         No

average_volume i get nan only
hence i guess my output is no for all dates
plz suggest some thing
thank you

ok so my data is like i download the EOD data for stock market which for all stocks
my rest of the code goes through that and makes a new excel file with all the details
i am adding few calculation columes in there. like vwap avg vol and all

so i get a saperate file for each stock with its details and deffirent calculation. so i can make my scanner

tried this

```
  def add_vol_breakout_column(self, df):
  
        average_volume = df['VOLUME'].rolling(window=21).mean()
        print(average_volume)
        volume_breakout = df['VOLUME'] > (average_volume * 3)
        df['VolBrkOut'] = np.where(volume_breakout, 'Yes', 'No')
        print(f"Updated DataFrame:\n{df}")
        return df
```

got this
`1497   NaN Name: VOLUME, dtype: float64 Updated DataFrame: SYMBOL        DATE  PCLOSE   OPEN  ...  DELIV_QTY  DELIV_PER  VWAP  VolBrkOut 1497  SATINDLTD  05-06-2023    72.9  73.45  ...     223886      65.52  72.0         No`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the source of the issue is the window function. The first 21 values are going to be NaN's (not a numbers) because there aren't 21 values behind them. In order to fix this, we can use '.fillna(x)', where x is an arbitrary integer. I wrote some sample code where I generated fake data then preformed the same operation below:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "VOLUME": [random.random() for i in range(300)],
    "PRICE": [random.random() for i in range(300)]
})

df['AVG_VOLUME'] = df['VOLUME'].rolling(21).mean()

df['AVG_VOLUME'] = df['AVG_VOLUME'].fillna(0)

df['VolBrkOut'] = df['VOLUME'] > df['AVG_VOLUME'] * 3
```

I would use true/false instead of Yes/No, as it has the same meaning/readability, yet is much more functional in code. If you later need to backtest and check if there is a breakout, then checking a boolean is much simpler and faster than checking string equality

Comment: ok ill go with true/ false.
i am sorting my date from new to old so it is importtant to find the true value in the start only  . can we start to calculate this from below so if old date i dont get a true or false that will not matter , i hope i was able to explain it. thank you for the help and time

Comment: The easiest way to do this would simply be to sort so that you have old->new, and then resort from new to old. Otherwise, instead of using df.rolling(), you can create a for loop, and simply do df['Average_Volume'] = pd.Series([df['VOLUME'][max(i-21, 0):i].mean() for i in range(df['VOLUME'].size())]. This will default to using all values from 0 to i when i < 21

Comment: def add_vol_breakout_column(self, df):
        reversed_df = df[::-1].copy()  # Reverse the entire DataFrame and create a copy
        average_volume = df['VOLUME'].rolling(window=21, min_periods=1).mean()
        volume_breakout = reversed_df['VOLUME'].gt(average_volume * 3)
        reversed_df.loc[:, 'VolBrkOut'] = volume_breakout  # Use .loc to set the 'VolBrkOut' column
        result_df = reversed_df[::-1]  # Reverse the DataFrame back to the original order
        return result_df
     i have come up with this do you feel it will work? i mean the logic

Comment: Yeah, looks about right, much cleaner too